# Error with OpenGL3 when running War Thunder on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

```
<aces> reports fatal error

Error initializing video (OpenGL3):
../../prog/engine2/drv/drv3d_GL3/linux_main.cpp, 528: init_info()
failed

Send this report to developers or try to fix causes and restart game
(aces)
```

I visited http://www.warthunder.com and they said it could be from my drivers, but my drivers are all up to date.

PS: my PC handled such games but with Windows 7.

Comment: Could well be your drivers. What is your GPU and what is your driver version.